# How to get an authorisation token for MS graph api using a saml assertion

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, saml, bearer-token

We use sso to log in to Office365 and our own intranet. The sso process returns a saml2 assertion, which is available to my code.

I was hoping to use this to get an authorisation token to access the graph api.

I have followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-saml-bearer-assertion

and I end up with an error: "AADSTS50107: The requested federation realm object 'https://sts.windows.net/xyzzy/' does not exist."

I have come to the conclusion that this is because our Office365 domain is managed, not federated, and that this flow won't work with a managed domain (though it's not obvious why not).

I have also followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#saml-assertions-obtained-with-an-oauth20-obo-flow

and I end up with a different error: "AADSTS700001: Application: spn:xyzzy needs to opt-in for 'aio' optional claim for On Behalf Of flow to work with SAML tokens issued to this application". The application it refers to here is the application used in the SSO, when we originally got the saml assertion (and not the application used to get the authorisation token for graph api).

I don't know how to opt-in for 'aio' optional claim. This claim doesn't appear in the list in the application config.

I would be grateful for any help in getting past either of these two errors, or for any alternative approach that would enable me to get an authorisation token for graph api using the saml assertion.

An example of the saml assertion I am trying to use:

```xml
<Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_nnnnnnnn-9ed2-4511-8f04-nnnnnnnnn" IssueInstant="2020-01-16T16:12:44.389Z" Version="2.0">
  <Issuer>https://sts.windows.net/nnnnnnnn-187d-415b-87e6-nnnnnnnn8a01/</Issuer>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
      <Reference URI="#_nnnnnnnn-9ed2-4511-8f04-nnnnnnnn1800">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue>mEWbTMcoHmsT1bcWK2/nnnnnnnnm+tpKxEgjXCo7uU=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>rEGA7emFjnJhAfUQ24PXcIOPAYBA5RXoj8+MsA2PnXDMMs2NfQkfp7F4n7z5v8PEJevTuqVpCVpSKBUL1pZDcKSs4mQ/gaPyFXD7u7yMyOSSyPDKmYHEVz4COA1JFTzvrQT5KTsNl0wEAIkwZcQKC+uSMr7Uj36bthqnnnnnnnnF8LFopSTayXa2IlxnccY/7zUxs5Sz1ZVCs8cqS81LJV7H2QGbNDJ1FXO9DYFkUdN81h5Ik+tXNhXnVFV/P0GTkX6KRYoVuqzZZQqgSoxsnAb4irKRYSSZ8cXsi9af2b+gIVZGJsdiMz7MLbdV2yLDjokKbNrkwQAO+VaUeZTUA==</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
  <Subject>
    <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">nnnnnnnnavitA3FPq9Bqtu6d3UlysiFOxjMX_je3u-k</NameID>
    <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"/>
  </Subject>
  <Conditions NotBefore="2020-01-16T16:07:44.248Z" NotOnOrAfter="2020-01-16T17:12:44.248Z">
    <AudienceRestriction>
      <Audience>spn:nnnnnnnn-900b-4a82-b65f-3975nnnnnnnn</Audience>
    </AudienceRestriction>
  </Conditions>
  <AttributeStatement>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid">
      <AttributeValue>nnnnnnnn-187d-415b-87e6-295ennnnnnnn</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier">
      <AttributeValue>nnnnnnnn-2111-48e1-ac4b-726nnnnnnnn</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
      <AttributeValue>nnnnnn.nnnnnn@nn.nnng</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname">
      <AttributeValue>nnnnnn</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname">
      <AttributeValue>nnnnn</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname">
      <AttributeValue>nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider">
      <AttributeValue>https://sts.windows.net/nnnnnnnn-187d-415b-87e6-295e9nnnnnnnn/</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences">
      <AttributeValue>http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/password</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </AttributeStatement>
  <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2020-01-14T15:47:10.396Z">
    <AuthnContext>
      <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
    </AuthnContext>
  </AuthnStatement>
</Assertion>
```

Comment: can you rephrase your question? I think you are saying: you want to create an app that uses graph API, that uses the current logged in user permissions.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I've tried two different routes, and hit roadblocks on each. I'm looking for a way round the roadblocks, or an alternative route. FWIW I'm programming in Java.

Comment: @cmgharris can you share more detail about your sso and intranet setup? also can you share a saml2 assertion?

Comment: @Alfredo Revilla, I have added an example of the saml2 assertion I receive back from SSO, and which I am trying to use. Parts are obfuscated.
I'm not sure what you want to know about my sso and intranet setup - can you be more specific?

Comment: @cmgharris how do you obtain the saml token? If it's interactively using a browser and as detailed in the [refered document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-saml-bearer-assertion): you can make an OAuth request to get an access token for the API. When the browser is redirected to Azure AD to authenticate the user, the browser will pick up the session from the SAML sign-in and the user doesn't need to enter their credentials.

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla as you surmise, I obtained the saml assertion interactively using a browser. Having got access to the saml assertion on the server, I was hoping to use it to get the graph api authorisation token without having to go via another browser redirect, which as you suggest, may well be a solution. In theory it seems it should be possible to get the authorisation directly from the server, but in practice I have hit the roadblocks described in my original question.

Comment: hi there, any update on this issue? I would also like to call azure ad graph api using saml2 response. thanks

Comment: @hksfho, I raised a question with Microsoft support. Unfortunately I've now lost the link to their answer, but essentially it said that what I was hoping to do was not possible. I think the solution is to redirect via the browser, as suggested by AlfredoRevilla in his comment above, though I haven't tried it.